# Android create and populate list layout programmatically

Tags: android, listview, android-xml

I can't use listview because this layout will already requires scrolling. So this leaves me at a problem: how to create my tables.

What I know:

- The size of the JSON array

I was going to try to make every cell in XML and do a for loop in the code, but my predicament is that I can't `findViewById` very well, because the `R.id.myId` names are difficult to account for, and are integers instead of strings. (probably a problem not as large as I am making it).

[image]

So here, I know the server call will return a json array with up to 5 objects in it. How can I populate my view?

I am using a LinearLayout for each row, much like I would be preparing a custom list view in preparation.

Insight appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you need it to be a ListView?  If not you could try a LinearLayout with a vertical orientation as the container for your list.  Just put the container in your xml and you can programatically add the rows that you generate using `addView()`.

Comment: oh, it isn't going to be a listview because of the scrolling within scrollview problem. So I'll consider your other suggestion

Comment: Use table layout we can dynamically addviews   to it

Comment: Yes, a TableLayout would work too.  If you decide to go with that, remember that each of the rows would need to be wrapped in a TableRow, and that the spacing of your columns will depend on how many children each of your LinearLayout rows has.

Comment: I am new to doing tablelayouts programmatically, can you help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622880/android-tablelayout-trouble-adding-views