# android tablelayout trouble, adding views

Tags: android, xml, view, android-linearlayout, tablelayout

I am having trouble with `View leader` , I'm not sure what the second parameter is supposed to be

```
        TableLayout leaderTable = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.leaderTable);            

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setId(i);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        View leader = new View(UserView.this, null, R.id.leaderLayout);

        TextView number = (TextView)leader.findViewById(R.id.numberView);
        number.setText(String.valueOf(i+1));

        tr.addView(leader);

        leaderTable.addView(tr);
```

The problem is that my `TextView` is null, despite being a subview of `leader.`

Pretty confused about this issue, and this is my XML

```
<TableLayout 
                 android:id="@+id/leaderTable"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center">

            </TableLayout>
```

do I need to do more with the XML? I don't have need to include the tablerows in it do I?

`R.id.leaderLayout` is its own xml file, a linearlayout with that id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the developer page for the View constructors:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#View%28android.content.Context%29

The second and third parameters for a View are used if you want this view to have certain attributes or styles set upon the creation of that view.

It looks like you actually want your variable `leader` to be inflated.  This will take a layout defined in xml and assign it to dynamically created view.  You said that your leaderLayout is a LinearLayout, so it would look something like this.

```
//Initialize the layout inflator, do this once and use it to inflate as many views as you want
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

//Assign your custom view to the variable leader
LinearLayout leader = (LinearLayout) inflator.inflate(R.layout.leaderLayout, tr);
```

The first parameter for inflate is R.layout.*nameOfYourXmlFile*.  The second is the ViewGroup that will be the parent of your inflated View.  Once this is done, you can use `findViewById` on leader to get the child views in your Xml file, add more children dynamically, and add it as a child of your TableRow.

Here's the developer page for LayoutInflator, in case you're curious about other usages of the `inflate` method.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

Comment: I have a new error now, here is what I am really triyng to do http://codepad.org/3c4NNFlY  , on the second pass of the forloop the addView fails with `05-16 13:34:05.143: E/AndroidRuntime(855): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
`  I imagined this would never be an issue, since all the views would be unique and created at each pass of the for loop

Comment: The second parameter for the method `inflate` is the parent of the inflated view.  Because a view cannot be the child of multiple parents, you're getting an error on `addView` because the parent has already been set. If you pass tr as a parameter, it should be added automatically with no need for addView.  Alternatively, you can call inflate with just the first parameter, your layout file, and call addView as you are.